# convert dataframe without header to dictionary with a row of number

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to put a dataframe into dictionary  ,with the first column as the key ,the numbers in a row would be the value . how should I do it ? I tried to_dict but did not work , my df has no header or rownumber.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with numbers as headers:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1, 2],
                 '2': [0.5, 0.75]},
                 index=['row1', 'row2'])
df.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'1': {'row1': 1, 'row2': 2}, '2': {'row1': 0.5, 'row2': 0.75}}
```

You may also specify column names when you read the data:

```
Cov = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", 
                  sep='\t', 
                  names=["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"])
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091877/how-to-add-header-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use dictionary comprehension (IIUC).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})
print (df)

    a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

d = {k:v for k, v in df.apply(lambda r: {r[0],",".join(r[1:].astype('str'))}, axis=1)}
print(d)
```

{1: '4,7', 2: '5,8', 3: '6,9'}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, the first column should be the keys while the numbers that follow are the values. Then, the values should be lists right?

Try this code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['C', 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        ['c', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        ['(', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [')', 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        ['O', 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    ]
)

print(df)
print('\n')

print({df.iloc[i][0]: df.iloc[i][1:].tolist() for i in df.T})
```

Here's the output:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5
0  C   5   4   3   2   1
1  c   6   7   8   9  10
2  (  11  12  13  14  15
3  )  16  17  18  19  20
4  O  21  22  23  24  25


{'C': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'c': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], '(': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], ')': [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 'O': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]}
```